# PlayFramework: Swagger CORS issue

Tags: playframework, swagger

Now I'm deploying my play2 app on ec2 and I encounter the problem. I get:

Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings.

When trying to get URL: my-ec2-domain:8080/swagger

Note: I use 8080 port on ec2.

On my local machine everything is ok.
localhost:9000/swagger returns API doc page

How I can fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Swagger-UI works with no problems when it is deployed in the same application server that's hosting the swagger specification. Otherwise, you need to enable CORS in the server hosting your specification.

You can find more information about it here - https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/CORS

Answer (score 0):

I find out that Swagger try to fetch localhost value instead of current domain.
Also swagger concatenates .json to the end of the url.

Comment: Looks like this should be an edit to the question instead of an answer.